# ¿Como crear un gridMousePos visible?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Pregunta trata de como crear un hacer que el cuadro que señala el ratón se vuelva visible o que haga notar al usuario el tamaño y donde puede colocarlo, el fin de esto es crear un sistema de creación de objetos de diferentes tamaños y los cuales ocuparan un espacio determinado en el terreno, un ejemplo puede ser el sistema de creación de objetos de Dragon City el cual al tu querer crear una tienda o algo te maraca el espacio que ocupa cuando mueves el ratón por el lugar.

mi código actual realiza esa función, pero no hace visible el cuadro:

```
        float floatMousePosX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
    int gridMousePosX = 10 * Mathf.RoundToInt(floatMousePosX/10);
```

Espero su apoyo, gracias.

Comment: Supongo que para ello ya tienes creado un sistema de cuadriculas. deberías concretar mas la pregunta, porque desconozco si tu sistema de cuadricula permite cualquier cosa, o un único objeto por cuadricula o 4 o x.

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero utilice la manera mas fácil cree un cubo plano y este se mueve con el ratón y al pisar clic se detiene y crea el objeto.